# Is there any management APIs for Azure website life cycle management?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

There are PowerShell cmdlets  for Azure website lifecycle management. But is there any management API for that? By any chance, Microsoft is planning to release management APIs for this in the near future?

Answer (score 1):

There **is** Management API for sure. Otherwise there wouldn't be a PowerShell cmdlet also.

By all chances Microsoft is going to release Management API for that. And I am sure that documentation will be out at latest when the service become GA (or Generally Available). Until then you can play with PowerShell.

Or, if you are really eager to explore Management API for Azure WebSite, I suggest that you start looking [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/tree/master/WindowsAzurePowershell/src/Management.WebSites/Cmdlets) and reverse engineer.

Comment: The REST Management API has methods for every product not in preview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx do you think they will add new methods when websites gets out of preview?